font IBMPlexMono not working on my vscode system(ubuntu )
I use Ubuntu and I want to use IBM Plex Mono font on my vscode, I have installed the .zip file of IBMPlexMono and this is my vscode settings: (IBM Plex Mono-Regular, monospace ), But still it's not reflecting on my vscode : ( please help, Thanks In advance have a nice day : )
I treid applying the font IBMPlexMono on my vscode but It is not working

Have you tried removing the -Regular part? That's given me trouble in the past with some fonts.

Yess I tried every possible versions: 1. IBMPlexMono  2. IBMPlexMono-Regular  3. IBM Plex Mono  4.IBM Plex Mono-Regular is there any possible versions ??
